# Multiple Errors When Uploading: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, plupload

I'm trying to get the plupload (http://www.plupload.com/) working in my PHP app.  Anything under 1mb in size uploads just fine.  Chunking is set to 1mb.  So if I attempt to upload something that is 3.5mb in the network inspector I see 4 calls to upload.php, the first is always fine, all subsequent calls error with: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away.  The error line number is 136, where I'm doing the insert.  How can I get rid of this error so I can upload large files with chunking?

Here is a snippet of the front end setup of the plupload...

```
 $(function() {
        $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
            // General settings
            //runtimes : 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5,html4',
            runtimes : 'html5,html4',
            url : 'upload.php',
            max_file_size : '5mb',
            chunk_size : '1mb',
            unique_names : false,
            multiple_queues : true,
            // Resize images on clientside if we can
            //resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},

            multipart_params : {doc_id : "<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>"},

            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters : [
                {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
                {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"},
                {title : "PDFs", extensions : "pdf"},
                {title : "Word Docs", extensions : "doc,docx"}
            ],
```

Here is the backend upload.php file (line 136 is where the error is happening)...

```
<?php
require_once("lib_protected_page_no_log.php");
/**
 * upload.php
 *
 * Copyright 2009, Moxiecode Systems AB
 * Released under GPL License.
 *
 * License: http://www.plupload.com/license
 * Contributing: http://www.plupload.com/contributing
 */

// HTTP headers for no cache etc
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

// Settings
//$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir");
//$targetDir = 'uploads';

$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Get parameters
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);

// Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {
    $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
    $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
    $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

    $count = 1;
    while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b))
        $count++;

    $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir))
    @mkdir($targetDir);

// Remove old temp files
if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
    if (is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))) {
        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

            // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
            if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge) && ($tmpfilePath != "{$filePath}.part")) {
                @unlink($tmpfilePath);
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    } else {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "dir" : "'.$targetDir.'"}');
    }
}

// Look for the content type header
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];

if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];

// Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions didn't support multipart in HTML5
if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Open temp file
        $out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = @fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
            @fclose($in);
            @fclose($out);
            @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
} else {
    // Open temp file
    $out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
    if ($out) {
        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
        $in = @fopen("php://input", "rb");

        if ($in) {
            while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                fwrite($out, $buff);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

        @fclose($in);
        @fclose($out);
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);

    $fp      = fopen($filePath, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($filePath));
    //$content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    $res = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO attachedfiles (doc_id, filename, filetype, filesize, content, uploadbyuser_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $res->execute(array($_REQUEST['doc_id'],basename($filePath),pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),filesize($filePath),$content,$_SESSION['user_id']));
}

die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "dir" : "'.$targetDir.'"}');
```

My database handle looks like this which is in the include at the top of upload.php...

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$libDBHostname;dbname=$libDBDatabase", $libDBUsername, $libDBPassword);    
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true );
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    //echo 'Connected to database';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Usually [`the packet is too large`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).

Comment: max_allowed_packet = 1048576

Comment: Yup. So, make it at least as large as the largest file you want to `INSERT` (+a bit extra for query overhead), or use `content=CONCAT(content,'newdata')` in `UPDATE`'s perhaps.

Comment: Also, if you get it on the 2nd request already... there's something wrong with either the `$chunks` or `$chunk` variable, as this shouldn't do an `INSERT` yet if I read this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are reading the issue correctly.  Still trying to find where to edit the max_allowed_packet on this server. This is a new setup I'm not familiar with.  Inside mysql.ini all I see is this: ; Enable mysql extension module
extension=mysql.so

Comment: It's not a `PHP` settings, it's one of your database (or: your database sets the maximum, a client can define a lower one). So, look in the `MySQL` config. On the other matter: if you see 4 requests, can you see what the `$_REQUEST['chunk']` & `$_REQUEST['chunks']` values are?

Comment: Upping the max_allowed_packets did the trick! I guess the errors were causing the chunks logic to not function properly because I just verified it's working now.  With a large file there were multiple calls to upload.php but only the final image was inserted in the DB.  Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44919/discussion-between-gfrobenius-and-wrikken)

Comment: @Wrikken I posted a follow up question to this one.  Should be an easy one for you if you want the points: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21616100/3112803