# MySql max_allowed_packet Resets When Server Reboots

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a new 1&1 Linux test server with PHP and MySql.  I need the `max_allowed_packet=6M`.  So I connect to MySql and run `set global max_allowed_packet=6291456` and then my process works great.  But when the servers restarts at night it goes back to the default of `max_allowed_packet = 1048576`.  I added `max_allowed_packet=6M` to the `etc/my.cnf` file.  Is there somewhere else I need to set this?

Comment: What section did you add it to?

Comment: my.cnf should do it. did you add it to the right section? there's multiple ones in there: server settings, client settings, global settings, etc...

Comment: I added it at the very bottom.  What signifies a "section"?  Sorry new to this.  A few lines above it I see `[mysqld_safe]`.  Do those brackets signify a section?  Right above `max_allowed_packet=6M` I have `timezone=UTC` and that seems to stick after reboots.

Comment: @gfrobenius: yep, it should be put to `[mysqld]`

Comment: Hmmm, ok, how come the `timezone=UTC` sticks?

Comment: It is as zerkms says..  And `timezone` is usually a client variable, although you could set the default for the server as well. Are you sure it 'sticks' there for the server? 'cause I can very well imagine deleting it there only affects clients, not the server itself.